# Can not create gradle project in STS 3.6.0

Tags: spring, gradle

I am using Spring Tool Suite (sts) Version: 3.6.0.RELEASE for creating a new Gradle project from File > New > project > gradle and I had given the name GradleProjectTest and I had chose JavaQuickstart form sample project dropdown, after that I am seeing this popup window Create gradle project(s) for the past half hour or so the progress is only at 0 %. So what am I missing, why is it still in 0 % ? or How do I create a new Gradle project in STS 3.6.0 ?

Comment: Add more information. Provide a screenshot or copy the messages from logs. Show your homework before asking.

Comment: @SureshKoya, No error messages, that popup window stays there for a long time at 0, moreover I tried to add the screen shots to this post, but unfortunately the user should have minimum of 10 reputations to do that. So is there any other way to share the screen shot ?